# Mule ESB 3.2.x: HTTPS Transport bad_certificate error?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, mule, keytool

I have a need to use a self-signed (or unsigned) certificate as a certificate for an HTTPS listener for an inbound endpoint to one of my flows. I have tried several methods to generate certificates, but I always get an error when the listener attempts to read a request:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

Google seems to think that the `bad_certificate` message has something to do with the trust store.  I continue to see the same error with or without the mule `tls-server` configuration which is supposed to define the trust store.

I've used several different mechanisms to create the certificate:

- The method using keytool in the [mule documentation for the HTTPS Transport](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference)
- A method described for [weblogic, using keytool](http://blogbypuneeth.wordpress.com/2011/01/15/steps-to-generate-self-signed-certificates-using-keytool/)
- A method described for [Apache, using openssl](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html), which I then imported into a java keystore using keytool
- A variety of other mechanisms that are mostly variations of the above.

I have tried both with and without the `tls-server` and `tls-client` elements configured, all as described in the mule documentation.

I am at my wit's end trying to determine what key types are acceptable to Mule, and what the root cause of the issue is. Any advise is appreciated.

My configurations and error logs follow (omitting various boilerplate content)

**mule-config.xml**

```
<https:connector name="connectorName">
    <!-- only one key, alias 'mule' -->
    <https:tls-key-store path="/opt/mule/keys/keystore.jks" keyPassword="thePassword" storePassword="thePassword"/>
    <!-- I've also tried the following, same error occurs both with or without this parameter -->
    <https:tls-server path="/opt/mule/keys/keystore.jks storePassword="thePassword"/>
</https:connector>

<flow name="theFlow">
    <https:inbound-endpoint host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" connector-ref="connectorName"/>
    <!-- stuff: not important, works with http -->
</flow>
```

This configuration loads correctly, but then when I attempt to post a request using the same method that works with HTTP (but using https:// instead) I get the following error, and no response back (not a 500 error, or anything, connection is just closed). This specific run is from the key I generated using the instructions on the mulesoft documentation for HTTPS Transport, but it is not any different from the error I get using any other method.

**Error Listing**

```
[ERROR] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy - Caught exception in Exception Strategy: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1571)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:103)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:689)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ServerHandshaker.java:1279)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientFinished(ServerHandshaker.java:1239)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:225)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:185)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Finally, thanks for your time reading this far.

**UPDATE**

I've started to get a different stack trace, but the same error. The change? The key and the keystore now have different passwords.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:50)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:219)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readRequest(HttpServerConnection.java:185)
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:155)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I added the key to the .../jre/lib/security/cacerts file as a trusted certificate.  No change.

Answer (score 1):

The method for creating a self-signed certificate shown in the Mule doc works: I've used it several times. I tried it again and it works with your configuration, except that I removed `https:tls-server`, which is useless.

Here are the steps I followed:

- Create the keystore with: `keytool -genkey -alias mule -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks` (I used "thePassword" for both the keystore and the key passwords).
- Configured Mule like this:

  ```
  <https:connector name="connectorName">
      <https:tls-key-store
          path="...path.../keystore.jks"
          keyPassword="thePassword" storePassword="thePassword" />
  </https:connector>

  <flow name="theFlow">
      <https:inbound-endpoint host="0.0.0.0" port="8081"
          connector-ref="connectorName" />
      <set-payload value="w00t" />
  </flow>
  ```
- Tested with:

  ```
  $ curl -vk https://localhost:8081
  * About to connect() to localhost port 8081 (#0)
  *   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
  * successfully set certificate verify locations:
  *   CAfile: none
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  * SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
  * Server certificate:
  *    subject: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=Unknown
  *    start date: 2013-05-15 18:20:34 GMT
  *    expire date: 2013-08-13 18:20:34 GMT
  *    common name: Unknown (does not match 'localhost')
  *    issuer: C=Unknown; ST=Unknown; L=Unknown; O=Unknown; OU=Unknown; CN=Unknown
  *    SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
  > GET / HTTP/1.1
  > User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
  > Host: localhost:8081
  > Accept: */*
  > 
  < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  < Date: Wed, 15 May 2013 11:24:24 -0700
  < Server: Mule Core/3.4.0
  < X-MULE_SESSION: 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
  < X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
  < LOCAL_CERTIFICATES: [Ljava.security.cert.X509Certificate;@1c5e22a
  < Content-Type: text/plain
  < Content-Length: 4
  < Connection: close
  < 
  * Closing connection #0
  * SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
  w00t
  ```

Comment: Actually, I'm not using mule to call this endpoint, rather I'm listening in mule, and calling from external service (post from a browser client, to test.  Proven to work with HTTP already).  adding tls-client does not change the result.

Comment: Did you accept the bogus certificate warning in the browser when calling the HTTPS endpoint?

Comment: There was no warning; mule closed the connection without responding.

Comment: OK so really something is corrupted in the KeyStore or maybe the passwords are wrong. Are you sure there is a password set on the key? Not just on the keystore?

Comment: Yes. I can verify that by interrogating using `keytool -list` for the keystore.  I can verify the key password by using `keytool -keypasswd` setting it to something else then back again.

Comment: For the record, according to keytool, the keystore is not corrupted and the key is valid.

Comment: Good, it's something else then.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the SSL handshake? 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: No, I didn't try that.  I think the issue has got to be more basic, because it appears to currently be an issue entirely within mule.  I came to this conclusion due to the fact I never get a response from the server in the client (while I didn't debug the ssl connection as linked, I did validate that the connection is closed with no traffic back from the server).

Comment: Since it's bogus I guess you'd have no problem sharing your `keystore.jks` somewhere so we can try it and see what happens?

Comment: Can you clarify if you tried using different keystores for tls-key-store and tls-server?  The former should contain a private key and public cert for identification, and the latter is the trust store and should contain only public certs of trusted servers.

Comment: I've tried both the same, and different key stores.  The key is supposed to be self-signed, so I suppose the key in the trust store should be the same as the key in the key store.  The documentation on how to generate a signed key using keytool is somewhat murky.

Comment: @DavidDossot: would normally be happy to, but this would violate too many directives my employer insists on. But you can generate your own the same way I did by using the command from the mule document referenced in the question.  If there are specific outputs you'd like to see, I can run commands and paste results.  I know this is suboptimal and I apologize but my hands are tied in this case.

Comment: Sounds like a fun employer to work for :) I tried the whole procedure and used your config (with one slight change) and it works perfectly. See my revised answer.

Comment: Are you testing with version 3.4 or 3.2 (which is our config)?

Comment: I wonder if our 3.2.1 has a bug in handling self-signed certs.  I'll have to run some more tests.

Comment: Get Mule 3.4.0 and try your app on it... 3.2.1 is so old anyway, more than time to upgrade :D

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone else.  I'm running Mule EE 3.5.0 with jdk1.6.0_45.  The command listed above would not generate a compatible keystore.  The keystore was fine when running in studio but would not work on the standalone ESB.

I reviewed the keystore used on the mule-security-example3.5.0 application and found differences.  I used KeyStore Explorer to create a keystore that had these attributes

Size: 1024
Version: 1
Alg: MD5 with RSA

Perhaps there is something off with the configuration on my instance of Mule EE; if someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Using a key with the above attributes will work with EE 3.5.0 which was downloaded from the customer portal this week.